# Обязательное переопределение метода

Tags: java

Как создать метод в супер-классе, который обязательно должен быть переопределен в подклассах. Создавать абстрактный класс нельзя.

Comment: Если все методы абстрактные, создайте интерфейс.

Comment: Я наоборот сказал, что у меня только один метод дожнен быть как бы "Абстрактный"

Comment: В абстрактном классе может быть и один абстрактный метод, а остальные неабстрактные.

Comment: _"Создавать абстрактный класс нельзя, т.к. там все методы абстрактные"_ - это неправда. В абстрактном классе вполне себе могут быть неабстрактные методы.

Comment: Я имею ввиду следующее: если есть хоть одни абстрактный метод, то класс нужно делать абстрактным, а мне не нужно делать его абстрактным, т.к. в нем есть конструктор, и мне нужно создавать экземпляр этого класса напрямую.

Comment: Без метода? Как вы это себе представляете?

Comment: В этом-то и проблема

Comment: Все, спасибо @Regent, я обдумал ваш ответ, и понял как это реализовать, спасибо большое :)

Comment: @Razor на здоровье. К какому выводу/решению вы пришли?

Comment: @Regent Я сделал класс абстрактным и метод объявил абстрактным (заблуждался что в абстрактном классе все методы абстрактные). А весь код конструктора просто вынес в класс - фабрику.

Comment: @Razor тогда давайте я ещё скажу, что в абстрактном классе могут быть конструкторы. Более того: если ни одного конструктора в абстрактном классе вы не создадите, то в нём всё равно будет конструктор по умолчанию, который также будет вызываться в конструкторе класса-наследника.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как создать метод в супер-классе, который обязательно должен быть переопределен в подклассах.

Для того, чтобы метод суперкласса обязательно должен быть переопределен в подклассе, следует объявить этот метод в суперклассе абстрактным.

Если требуется, чтобы в суперклассе данный метод не был абстрактным, возможно, такое поведение можно реализовать с помощью аннотаций, но в этом по сути нет смысла: если метод обязательно переопределен в подклассе, то зачем нужна его реализация в суперклассе?

> Создавать абстрактный класс нельзя, т.к. там все методы абстрактные

Создать экземпляр абстрактного класса нельзя, да, но в абстрактном классе могут быть методы, которые имеют реализацию, то есть совсем необязательно чтобы все методы были абстрактными.

Comment: Я уже понял, мало работал с абстрактными методами и классами, а теперь понял, решение найдено, спасибо.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Строго говоря, да, Вы правы. Поправил.